# Is there a shortcut to finding the sign of the derivative of a polynomial without doing the full computation?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, polynomials

I have a recursive polynomial definition that essentially has lead me to this mess:

$$B_{1,d}(t)=\sum^d_{i=1} \bigg(\frac{t-k_i}{k_{1+d} - k_i}B_{d-i, i}(t)\bigg) + \prod^{d}_{i=1}\bigg(\frac{k_{d+2-t}}{k_{d+2}-k_{i+1}}\bigg)B_{d,0}(t)$$

There's certain things I can prove in a couple of lines from that, such as the highest exponent (degree) of the polynomial the sign of that term, the 0 roots...

Can I use any of this and a theorem to show that that polynomial is increasing over a given interval (I know it does because I plotted it).

I am trying to prove this for essentially a superclass of such polynomials, but one istance is the yellow curve in this graph:

[image]